# How to open BitLocker Drive Encryption windows using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

Is there a command to open the BitLocker Drive Encryption windows using PowerShell (Control Panel\System and Security\BitLocker Drive Encryption)?  I do not want any changes I just want to open this window.

[image]

Comment: You have a module in PS for that. Go through [Unlock-BitLocker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/unlock-bitlocker?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
control /name Microsoft.BitLockerDriveEncryption
```